# Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

```
$replacements = array(
    '{order_id}' => $order_id, 
    '{site_url}' => $settings["site_url"], 
    '{email}' => $user_email, 
    '{last_name}' => $last_name, 
    '{phone}' => $phone, 
    '{order_total}' => currency_format($order_total), 
);

    foreach($replacements as $param => $value){
    $sms = str_replace($param, $value, $db2->f('sms'));
    $user_to = str_replace($param, $value, $db2->f('user_to'));
    $user_from = str_replace($param, $value, $db2->f('user_from'));
    $user_subject = str_replace($param, $value, $db2->f('user_subject'));
    $user_body = str_replace($param, $value, $user_body);
    $admin_to = str_replace($param, $value, $db2->f('admin_to'));
    $admin_from = str_replace($param, $value, $db2->f('admin_from'));
    $admin_subject = str_replace($param, $value, $db2->f('admin_subject'));
    $admin_body = str_replace($param, $value, $db2->f('admin_body'));
}
```

What is the problem? Why can't work? Array to string conversion....

Can anyone suggest how to reduce the number of lines of code in such a case?

Comment: What are you getting ? What is $db2 ? What are $order_id, $settings, etc...

Comment: When you ask a question on stack overfow. You should tell people what the problem is, not ask them :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819423/convert-this-associative-array-to-a-string-or-single-indexed-array

Comment: Read docs of [`str_replace`](http://docs.php.net/str_replace). You don't need this `foreach` loop. There is an example of exactly what you need.

Comment: @SilentGhost You think I don't read this? I've used before two arrays, templates and replace, but variables too much (much more than I described), and I thought somehow reduce the code...

Comment: @Luntegg: _variables too much_? What are you trying to say? There are too many variables? So make an array of the variables names and iterate over it.

Comment: @SilentGhost I'm trying to make it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$replacements = array(
    '{order_id}' => $order_id, 
    '{site_url}' => $settings["site_url"], 
    '{email}' => $user_email, 
    '{last_name}' => $last_name, 
    '{phone}' => $phone, 
    '{order_total}' => currency_format($order_total), 
);

$templates = array(
    'sms' => $db2->f('sms'), 
    'user_to' => $db2->f('user_to'), 
    'user_from' => $db2->f('user_from'), 
    'user_subject' => $db2->f('user_subject'), 
    'user_body' => $db2->f('user_body'), 
    'admin_to' => $db2->f('admin_to'), 
    'admin_from' => $db2->f('admin_from'), 
    'admin_subject' => $db2->f('admin_subject'), 
    'admin_body' => $db2->f('admin_body')
);

foreach($templates as $way => $tmp){
    $templates[$way] = strtr($tmp, $replacements);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwritting $user_body each time you loop.
Try that:

```
$replacements = array(
    '{order_id}' => $order_id, 
    '{site_url}' => $settings["site_url"], 
    '{email}' => $user_email, 
    '{last_name}' => $last_name, 
    '{phone}' => $phone, 
    '{order_total}' => currency_format($order_total), 
);

$user_body = $db2->f('user_body');
foreach($replacements as $param => $value){
    $user_body = str_replace($param, $value, $user_body);
}

echo $user_body;
```

Comment: What notice are you talking about ?

Comment: Maybe $db2->f() is returning an array. We can't just guess.

Comment: Use var_dump() on every suspicious variable. That will show you if one of them is an array